# Find files with maxdepth 2 in Linux and move to respective folder

Tags: linux, find, mv

I have the following command to move files from one directory to another, which works fine.

```
find /volume1/backup/ -type f -mtime +365 -exec mv -v "{}" /usb1/backup/ \;
```

However, I've changed the directory structure in /backup to have subdirectories (one depth). Now I want to copy the files in those subdirs to their respective dirs on the /usb1 volume. I've already included -maxdepth 2 and -mindepth 2, but I'm clueless as what to do next...

```
find /volume1/backup/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -mtime +365 -exec mv -v "{}" /usb1/backup/ \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't been able to find a short answer, but the following did the trick for me :

```
for d in $(find /volume1/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
do
  for f in $(find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +365 -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0)
  do
    mv -v $f /usb1/backup/$(basename $d)/;
  done
done
```

Comment: If anyone has a one-liner, feel free to add it.